# Make text in table fit in page

Tags: latex

I have a latex table that extends beyond the page like this

[image]

The latex code looks as follows

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{longtable}
% Note: It may be necessary to compile the document several times to get a multi-page table to line up properly
\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Term            & Explanation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & Comment \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
Product Owner   & Otto \& Lene                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &         \\ \hline
Lene            & Team Manager                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &         \\ \hline
Otto            & Software Engineer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               &         \\ \hline
Angular         & Frontend javascript framework to build modern single page applications                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          &         \\ \hline
GFS Upload      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}GFS Upload is an internal system used by employees at  to insert the extra financial statements that haven't been inserted automatically yet.\\ \\ While there are different financial information the different places want GFS upload sorts by having Chart Bookings and Account Bookings.\end{tabular} &         \\ \hline
Chart Booking   & Chart Booking is financial statements used to report to Nationalbanken.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         &         \\ \hline
Account Booking & Account booking is used for internal  account reporting.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             &         \\ \hline
Cloud 2         &  cloud service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       &         \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

I would like the text to fit inside the page, automatically inserting linebreaks. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a column of fixed width. You will have to find out yourself which width you'll need for your document, as this will depend from the exact page geometry you use and unfortunately you only provided a not-compilable code fragment and no minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}



\begin{document}

% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{longtable}
% Note: It may be necessary to compile the document several times to get a multi-page table to line up properly
\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|p{9.7cm}|l|}
\hline
Term            & Explanation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & Comment \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
Product Owner   & Otto \& Lene                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &         \\ \hline
Lene            & Team Manager                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &         \\ \hline
Otto            & Software Engineer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               &         \\ \hline
Angular         & Frontend javascript framework to build modern single page applications                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          &         \\ \hline
GFS Upload & GFS Upload is an internal system used by employees at  to insert the extra financial statements that haven't been inserted automatically yet. While there are different financial information the different places want GFS upload sorts by having Chart Bookings and Account Bookings. & \\ \hline
Chart Booking   & Chart Booking is financial statements used to report to Nationalbanken.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         &         \\ \hline
Account Booking & Account booking is used for internal  account reporting.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             &         \\ \hline
Cloud 2         &  cloud service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       &         \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @BorisGrunwald You're welcome. In the future, please provide a [mre] in your question.